# do not apply rewrite rule to a specific file extension

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2.4

I have an htaccess that will make some url rewrite on specific situations.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule \.php$ - [L,NC]
RewriteRule ^(?:favicon\.ico|(?:index|custom500|custom404)\.html)$ - [L,NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule .+ index.php?source=$0 [L,QSA]
```

Inside I have a rule that prevent index.html, custom404.html, custom500.php and favicon.ico to be included in the rewrite.
Now I am trying to add the same logic for any file that ends with pdf or jpg extension.
So I tried to add the pdf extension to the exclusion list

```
RewriteRule ^(?:favicon\.ico|(?:index|custom500|custom404)\.html|?:\*\.pdf)$ - [L,NC]
```

but apache will anyway serve this file as `index.php?source=myfile.pdf`
How can I add .pdf and .jpg to this list correctly?

Comment: `|?` in that place makes no sense syntactically, because the question mark would be considered a quantifier there.

Comment: If you don't want any rewrites at all for PDF files - then why not simply append `RewriteRule \.php$ - [L,NC]` accordingly? Getting the "alternative" `.pdf` integrated into _that_ pattern, seems a lot easier, I'd say.

Comment: @cbroe how you'd put it? and more important, why the ? is working correctly for the other two regexp in that rule?

Comment: Because in those other two places, the `?` does not stand on its own, but is part of the "non-capturing group" syntax, `(?:`

Comment: `RewriteRule \.php|\.pdf$ - [L,NC]`, and done - no? (Or `RewriteRule \.p(hp|df)$ - [L,NC]`, if anyone would really want to consider that an improvement.)

Comment: looks pretty straightforward... i was approaching it on the wrong side, thanks!